# Query object within an object

Tags: mongodb, passport.js

I'm using passport.js to store my users into my mongodb. A user object looks like this

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("545ac4930acf4b5394cbc244"),
   "local" : {
       "password" : [encrypted password],
       "email" : "john@domain.com",
       "level" : "super user",
   },
   "__v" : 0
}
```

I'm attempting to display all the users who are part of the "super user" group.

I'm finding this difficult as my data sits two levels within the object.

Comment: Use the dot notation: db.users.find({"local.level" : "super user"})

Comment: Thanks that works! How do I mark your response as the answer? Also how I do exactly the same but instead of returning the whole object just returning "password" & "email". Cheers

Comment: I added a complete answer, including information on how to return only some fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the dot notation like this:

```
db.users.find({"local.level" : "super user"})
```

To return only some fields, the [find](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find) has an optional projection argument. For the password and email you would do something like:

```
db.users.find({"local.level" : "super user"}, {"local.password":1, "local.email":1, "_id":0})
```

Note: the _id is always returned unless marked as 0 in the projection.